# I am using angular model ($uibmodal) display pop-up. Need to know how to handle backspace key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing a problem like when user click backspace on the model window, parent window gets navigating to previous page but pop-up doesn't close.Can I dismiss that pop-up by click backspace key ?

Comment: yes. better trigger the popup close event on window unload event callback function.

Comment: Could you please show some example to understand better ?